# IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device while installing pytorch

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytorch

l got the following error when installing **pytorch**

```
 pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.1.11.post5-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl 
Collecting torch==0.1.11.post5 from http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.1.11.post5-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Downloading http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.1.11.post5-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl (475.7MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 475.7MB 3.5MB/s
```

the following error

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 663, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 501, in unzip_file
    fp.write(data)
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

What's wrong ?  l don't understand the error coming from `/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/`

Comment: It's clearly stating "No space left on device" , `df -h` output will help to look at the issue better

Comment: I had the same problem while installing pytorch because of no space in hard drive

Answer (score 4):

In my case the system `/tmp` ran out of space, hence the error despite the installation path has enough space left.

`export TMPDIR=/where/you/have/enough/space/left` solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

faced and solved same problem,
when I `pip uninstall pipenv`, then no error occur, maybe you should uninstall some python packages.

Comment: not real solved, you should release some disk space.

Answer (score 0):

for me @user495285 answer made the trick (`export TMPDIR=/where/you/have/enough/space/left`)
Note that I tracked pytorch install space used on that specific location and at the peak, it needed 7.1GB on Sept2023 to install the following dist packages:

> *cmake-3.27.2 filelock-3.12.3 lit-16.0.6 mpmath-1.3.0 networkx-3.1 nvidia-cublas-cu11-11.10.3.66 nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11-11.7.101
> nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11-11.7.99 nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11-11.7.99
> nvidia-cudnn-cu11-8.5.0.96 nvidia-cufft-cu11-10.9.0.58
> nvidia-curand-cu11-10.2.10.91 nvidia-cusolver-cu11-11.4.0.1
> nvidia-cusparse-cu11-11.7.4.91 nvidia-nccl-cu11-2.14.3
> nvidia-nvtx-cu11-11.7.91 sympy-1.12 torch-2.0.1 triton-2.0.0
> typing-extensions-4.7.1*